# Cypress does not intercept GraphQL API calls

Tags: graphql, cypress

I am trying to intercept a graphql mutation to access its response. Cypress doesn't notice the request and `cy.wait()` times out.

**test**

```
describe('/profile', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    cy.server()
    cy.route({
      method: 'POST',
      url: Cypress.config().baseUrl + '/graphql',
    }).as('graphql')
    cy.fastLogin()
    cy.visit('/profile')
  })

  it('is possible to change password', () => {
    cy.get('[data-cy=change-password-btn]').click()

    cy.get('[name=oldPassword]').type(Cypress.config().password)
    cy.get('[name=newPassword]').type('password1')
    cy.get('[name=confirmNewPassword]').type('password1')
    cy.get('[data-cy=change-pw-form-btn]').click()

    cy.wait('@graphql').then(xhr => {
      cy.log(JSON.stringify(xhr.response.body))
    })

    cy.get('[data-cy=notification-container]').should(
      'contain',
      'Your password has been changed'
    )
  })
```

I found a common problem that many people were having was that they called `cy.server()` or `cy.route()` after `cy.visit()`. That's is not my case, but still the `cy.wait()` fails.

I have a NodeJS backend and ReactJS frontend if that makes any difference.

Any ideas?

Comment: Does that login request go via `fetch`, maybe? See https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/95

Comment: Yes, actually every graphql call goes via `fetch`. So that is why `cypress` didn't see them. I used this gist: https://gist.github.com/yagudaev/2ad1ef4a21a2d1cfe0e7d96afc7170bc to tranform `fetch` to `xhr` in my tests. Now I can see the queries in `cypress`, but the `cy.wait()` call still times out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cypress` wasn't seeing my `graphql` queries, because all of them went via `fetch`. I used this [gist](https://gist.github.com/yagudaev/2ad1ef4a21a2d1cfe0e7d96afc7170bc) to tranform `fetch` to `xhr`. Now I can see the `graphql` `POST` calls in `cypress` UI, but the `cy.wait()` still times out

Comment: Do you still need help with the timeouts? Can you include a screenshot of the network tab showing the graphql calls if so? Also you should try changing  url: Cypress.config().baseUrl + '/graphql' go  url: '/graphql'