# Cypress not seeing graphql request

Tags: graphql, cypress, apollo-client, e2e-testing, apollo-server

This seems to be a long lasting issue:

In cypress interface, my application cannot send any graphql request or receive any response. Because it is `fetch` type.

here is the network status in cypress:

[image]

But in normal browser, I actually have several graphql requests, like here:

[image]

I know there are already quite several discussions and workarounds, such as using an polyfill to solve this problem such as below:

- https://gist.github.com/yagudaev/2ad1ef4a21a2d1cfe0e7d96afc7170bc
- [Cypress does not intercept GraphQL API calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60827832/cypress-does-not-intercept-graphql-api-calls)

but unfortunately, they are not working in my case.

Appreciate to the help of any kinds.

p.s.: I am using cypress 8.3.0, React as the front-end, and using apollo client and apollo server for all graphql stuff.

---

EDIT:

samele intercept:

```js
   cy.intercept('POST', Cypress.env('backendpiUrl') + '/graphql', req => {
      if (req.body.operationName === 'updateItem') {
        req.alias = 'updateItemMutation';
      }
    });
```

sample cypress console:

[image]

You can see that all the requests are XHR based, no graphql's fetch request

Answer (score 3):

The links are old, `unfetch` polyfill is no longer necessary. Since the introduction of `cy.intercept()`, `fetch` is able to be waited on, stubbed etc.

Here's the docs [Working with GraphQL](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/testing-strategies/working-with-graphql) and an interesting atricle [Smart GraphQL Stubbing in Cypress](https://glebbahmutov.com/blog/smart-graphql-stubbing/) (Note `route2` is an early name for `intercept`)

More up-to-date, posted two days ago [bahmutov - todo-graphql-example](https://github.com/bahmutov/todo-graphql-example)

Key helper function from this package:

```js
import {
  ApolloClient,
  InMemoryCache,
  HttpLink,
  ApolloLink,
  concat,
} from '@apollo/client'

// adding custom header with the GraphQL operation name
// https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/networking/advanced-http-networking/
const operationNameLink = new ApolloLink((operation, forward) => {
  operation.setContext(({ headers }) => ({
    headers: {
      'x-gql-operation-name': operation.operationName,
      ...headers,
    },
  }))
  return forward(operation)
})

const httpLink = new HttpLink({ uri: 'http://localhost:3000' })

export const client = new ApolloClient({
  link: concat(operationNameLink, httpLink),
  fetchOptions: {
    mode: 'no-cors',
  },
  cache: new InMemoryCache(),
})
```

Sample test

```js
describe('GraphQL client', () => {
  // make individual GraphQL calls using the app's own client

  it('gets all todos (id, title)', () => {
    const query = gql`
      query listTodos {
        # operation name
        allTodos {
          # fields to pick
          id
          title
        }
      }
    `
    cy.wrap(
      client.query({
        query,
      }),
    )
      .its('data.allTodos')
      .should('have.length.gte', 2)
      .its('0')
      .should('deep.equal', {
        id: todos[0].id,
        title: todos[0].title,
        __typename: 'Todo',
      })
  })
```

Please show your test and the error (or failing intercept).

Comment: Thanks Paolo, I have updated the cypress console screenshot in my main content, please check it.

But what I am still confused is that, do you mean I have to intercept the graphql request before seeing it? I do use the code to intercept it, but still not seeing in the cypress